# How to show irreducibility

Tags: finite-fields, irreducible-polynomials, cryptography

I have a question.

I want to show  $x^8+x^4+x^3+x+1$ (which is used in AES) is irreducible on $GF(2)$.

I can try $2^5$ polynomial. But it is really challenging. Is there a another way?

Comment: Do you want irreducibility over $GF(2)$ or $GF(2^8)$ ? When you write that you "can try $2^8$ polynomials" it sounds like you mean to check all $2^8$ polynomials of degree $< 8$ over $GF(2)$ as potential factors ? In which case you would only need to check about $2^5$ cases since if there is a nontrivial factor there is one of degree $\leq 4$.

Comment: See : [Prove that the $x^8+x^4+x^3+x+1$ is irreducible over $\mathbb{Z}_2[x]$](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/77952/18298)

Comment: I edit it. I want irreducibility over GF(2)